# Calculating SHA-2 or SHA-3 hash

Tags: java, scala, hash

I need to calculate SHA-2 or SHA-3 of a file. I didn't file any code example showing how to get SHA-2 or SHA-3 of something. It seems even Apach doesn't it.

Is there anyone available?

Comment: Be careful here. SHA 384 is NOT the same as SHA-3.
 - SHA 384 == SHA2 with a 384 bit key
 - SHA 3 == Keccak (cfr http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-3)

A java implementation of Keccak can be found at https://github.com/kocakosm/pitaya/blob/master/src/org/kocakosm/pitaya/security/Keccak.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, apache commons does support SHA 256, SHA 384, and SHA 512. See [apache commons DigestUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html).

Comment: DigestUtils uses Java's internal SHA implementation which I believe is SHA-2. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2#Comparison_of_SHA_functions

Comment: Be careful here. SHA 384 is NOT the same as SHA-3.
 - SHA 384 == SHA2 with a 384 bit key
 - SHA 3 == Keccak (cfr http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-3)

A java implementation of Keccak can be found at https://github.com/kocakosm/pitaya/blob/master/src/org/kocakosm/pitaya/security/Keccak.java